# Getting this Error I/flutter (26554): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, rest

I am getting This Error

```
I/flutter (26554): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26554): <html>
I/flutter (26554): ^
```

When I try to make POST request to `https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers`

The payload is as given as thus (Inside postman)

```
{
    "amount": 500,
    "narration": "Test Int'l bank transfers",
    "currency": "USD",
    "beneficiary_name": "Mark Cuban",
    "meta": [
        {
            "AccountNumber": "09182972BH",
            "RoutingNumber": "0000000002993",
            "SwiftCode": "ABJG190",
            "BankName": "BANK OF AMERICA, N.A., SAN FRANCISCO, CA",
            "BeneficiaryName": "Mark Cuban",
            "BeneficiaryAddress": "San Francisco, 4 Newton",
            "BeneficiaryCountry": "US"
        }
    ]
}
```

It gives me this response (Having tested inside Postman, Which is correct)

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Transfer Queued Successfully",
    "data": {
        "id": 396427,
        "account_number": "FOREIGN-ACCOUNT",
        "bank_code": "FOREIGN-BANK",
        "full_name": "Mark Cuban",
        "created_at": "2023-03-10T20:30:52.000Z",
        "currency": "USD",
        "amount": 500,
        "fee": 40,
        "status": "NEW",
        "reference": "ebce2909fc3a57a7",
        "meta": [
            {
                "MerchantName": "TestLucas LLC",
                "SenderCountry": "NG",
                "AccountNumber": "FOREIGN-ACCOUNT",
                "RoutingNumber": "FOREIGN-BANK",
                "Sender": "TestLucas LLC",
                "Address": null,
                "MobileNumber": "23480000000000"
            }
        ],
        "narration": "Test Int'l bank transfers",
        "complete_message": "",
        "requires_approval": 0,
        "is_approved": 1,
        "bank_name": "FA-BANK"
    }
}
```

But when i test inside my flutter code, it gives me this Error

```
I/flutter (26554): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26554): <html>
I/flutter (26554): ^
```

Please See my Flutter code

```
    class UsTransferProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _reqMessage = '';

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  String get reqMessage => _reqMessage;

  void usTransfer({
    required String amount,
    required String narration,
    required String currency,
    required String bankName,
    required String accountNum,
    required String beneficiary_name,
    required String routingNumber,
    required String swiftCode,
    required String beneficiaryCountry,
    required String beneficiaryAddress,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    String url = 'https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers';

    String tokenUser = "FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X";
    final body = {
      "amount": amount,
      "narration": narration,
      "currency": currency,
      "beneficiary_name": beneficiary_name,
      "meta": [
        {
          "AccountNumber": accountNum,
          "RoutingNumber": routingNumber,
          "SwiftCode": swiftCode,
          "BankName": bankName,
          "BeneficiaryName": beneficiary_name,
          "BeneficiaryAddress": beneficiaryAddress,
          "BeneficiaryCountry": beneficiaryCountry,
        }
      ]
    };
    print(body);

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Charset': 'utf-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $tokenUser'
    };

    print(tokenUser);
    //making http request

    http.Response req = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: headers, body: json.encode(body));

    try {
      if (req.statusCode == 200 || req.statusCode == 201) {
        print(req.body);
        _isLoading = false;
        _reqMessage = "Transfer Successful";
        pushNotification(
            'Money Transfer Complete', 'Successfully sent $amount');
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        final res = json.decode(req.body);
        _isLoading = false;
        _reqMessage = '';
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      _isLoading = false;
      _reqMessage = 'No Internet Connection';
      notifyListeners();
      print(_);
    } catch (e) {
      _isLoading = false;
      _reqMessage = 'Check your Internet connection';
      notifyListeners();

      print(e);
    }
  }

  void clear() {
    _reqMessage = '';
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The code to call it Looks thus

```
Consumer<UsTransferProvider>(builder: (context, auth, child) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              if (auth.reqMessage != '') {
                showMessage(
                  message: auth.reqMessage,
                  context: context,
                );
              }
              auth.clear();
            });
            return customButton(
                tap: () {
                  if (amountController.text.isEmpty ||
                      narrationController.text.isEmpty ||
                      accountController.text.isEmpty ||
                      routingController.text.isEmpty ||
                      beneficiaryAddressController.text.isEmpty ||
                      beneficiaryCountryController.text.isEmpty ||
                      beneficiaryNameController.text.isEmpty ||
                      swifcodeController.text.isEmpty ||
                      _mybank.toString().isEmpty) {
                    showMessage(
                      message: "All field is required",
                      context: context,
                    );
                  } else {
                    auth.usTransfer(
                        amount: amountController.text,
                        narration: narrationController.text,
                        currency: selectCurrency,
                        bankName: _mybank.toString().trim(),
                        accountNum: accountController.text,
                        beneficiary_name: beneficiaryNameController.text,
                        routingNumber: routingController.text,
                        swiftCode: swifcodeController.text,
                        beneficiaryCountry: beneficiaryCountryController.text,
                        beneficiaryAddress: beneficiaryAddressController.text);
                  }
                },
                text: 'Send Money',
                textColor: white,
                color: primaryColor,
                status: auth.isLoading,
                borderColor: primaryColor);
          })
```

How Do i go from here?

Edit

As requested, my Postman Request is as thus

[image: ziochi.png]

Comment: Can you add to the question the way you call the method ```usTransfer``` please? To make it easier for those helping you.

Comment: @bqubique, pls have a Look again

Comment: The server is returning HTML not JSON. Print the HTML to the console and you may find an error message in there that helps you.

Comment: Also edit the question to show the Postman request.

Comment: One obvious difference is that, in your postman request, amount is an integer, but in your code it's a string, which is a different JSON type.

Comment: Change `final body = {"amount": amount,` to `final body = {'amount': int.parse(amount),`

Comment: @RichardHeap, thanks. Its fine now

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be sured this error is occurring only due to this amount variable, you can give hardcoded values to check all other parameter is passing exactly fine. if amount is `int`  like this `amount=500`(here i am considering 500 is temporary integer). then you can pass

```
final body ={
---
"amount":amount,
----
}
```

if amount is integer in string like `"500"` then you can follow below way

```
int? amountint=int.parse(amount.toString())
```

then

```
 final body ={
 
    if(amountint!=null)
    "amount":amountint,
 
    };
```

Comment: see edits and help pls